# Django UpdateView get name error: pk is not defined

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I get a name error: pk is not defined although I can see that the pk is passed to the view from the url.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from cashflow.views import cashflowView, SelectAccountView, CashflowEditView
from django.urls import path


app_name = 'cashflow'

urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^select_account', SelectAccountView.as_view(), name="select_account"),
       url(r'^$', cashflowView.as_view(), name="cashflow_processing"),
       path('edit/<pk>/', CashflowEditView.as_view(), name="cashflow_editing"),
]
```

views.py:

```
class CashflowEditView(UpdateView):
    model = ttransactions
    template_name = 'cashflow/cashflow_processing.html'
    form_class = CashflowForm
    success_url = 'cashflow'


    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(CashflowEditView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        transaction = ttransactions.objects.filter(pk=pk)
        transaction_lines = transaction_lines.objects.filter(transaction=transaction.id)
        return transaction, transaction_lines
```

I get the error on the line `transaction = ttransactions.objects.filter(pk=pk)`

When I run in debug I can see that pk is send to the view but when I use it on the object I get the error.

[image: Results from debug]

I will appreciate help to resolve the problem for me.

I added the print(kwargs) as specified and got this in the terminal:

```
    Internal Server Error: /cashflow/edit/42/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 4
7, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, i
n _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in
 view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in
 dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 189, i
n get
    self.object = self.get_object()
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py", line 30,
in get_object
    queryset = self.get_queryset()
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\aberni\cashflow\views.py", line 274, in get_queryset
    transaction = ttransactions.objects.filter(pk=pk)
NameError: name 'pk' is not defined
[06/Jan/2021 16:01:25] "GET /cashflow/edit/42/ HTTP/1.1" 500 86062
Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line
 1774, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'favicon.ico'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 4
7, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, i
n _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in
 view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in
 dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py", line 106,
 in get
    self.object = self.get_object()
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py", line 36,
in get_object
    queryset = queryset.filter(pk=pk)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 942, in f
ilter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 962, in _
filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 969, in _
filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1358,
 in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1377,
 in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1319,
 in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1165,
 in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 24, in
__init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 76, in
get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "C:\Users\94ber\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dev\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line
 1776, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'favicon.ico'.
[06/Jan/2021 16:01:26] "GET /favicon.ico/ HTTP/1.1" 500 138586
```

Answer (score 0):

`transaction = ttransactions.objects.filter(pk=pk)`

Where are you getting the variable `pk` from? Are you expecting it to come from kwargs? If so then it should be:

`transaction = ttransactions.objects.filter(pk=kwargs['pk'])`

Comment: pk originates from the url. The '42' is in the url. I get a KeyError 'pk' when I do the change as recommended

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch `pk` value from `kwargs` dictionary.

Try this:

```
def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    pk = int(kwargs['pk'])
    transaction = ttransactions.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    transaction_lines = transaction_lines.objects.filter(transaction=transaction.id)
    return transaction, transaction_lines
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I now however get a KeyError 'pk' on the line that is added. Please help again.

Comment: Okay can you `print kwargs` and share the output?

Comment: How do I print kwargs?

Comment: just write `print(kwargs)` by replacing `pk = int(kwargs['pk'])`

Comment: I feel stupid. I the print(kwags) line and is now getting different errors - see the trace back from the terminal that I added.

Answer (score 0):

It seems instead of the id, you got a different value which is the "favicon.ico" which was passed on your queryset parameter (based on the print(kwargs) output)

```
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'favicon.ico'
```

Answer (score -1):

def get_queryset(self, **kwargs)
insted of **kwargs you need to define pk
like this,
def get_queryset(self, pk)

try this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).